# Are there requirements for periodic inspection of your consumer unit? (UK)

Tags: electrical, uk

The house I am in has the sticker I pasted below on the consumer unit.

It "recommends" an inspection 3 years after the prior one. Is this a requirement? Even if it is not required, is it actually a useful recommendation or is it more of a marketing ploy on the part of the electrician?

In certain cases of old or outdated equipment, perhaps a periodic inspection is wise, but I would be very concerned if an electrician knew of a serious problem which required active monitoring but hasn't made efforts to just correct it. (Perhaps there are cases of homeowners who will only pay for the minimum...)

[image]

Thanks

Comment: It is usually homeowners who make unsuitable or unauthorized changes...

Comment: @SolarMike that could be a good rationale for a required inspection...

Answer (score 3):

There is not a requirement in owner-occupied single family dwellings to have periodic electrical inspections. There is in some rented homes or houses of multiple occupation (HMO).

Under BS7671 (the IET) Wiring Regulations the electrician is required to *recommend* an inspection period. I don't know why yours has put 3 years, for dwellings the interval is usually 5 for rented and 10 for owned.

> For rented accommodation, the maximum period recommended between the
>   initial inspection (when the installation was first put into service)
>   and the first periodic inspection and test is five years.

[NICEIC recommendation](https://www.niceic.com/landlord/managing-domestic-properties/how-often-should-i-get-my-electrical-installation)

> change of occupancy/10 years

[Intersafe electrical test providers](https://www.fixedtesting.com/testing-intervals/)

> Typical workplaces or environments which require 3 or 1 year Fixed
>   Wire Testing include: Spa hotels and leisure centres – 3 years

[Intersafe electrical test providers 2](https://www.intersafe.co.uk/news/how-often-should-fixed-wire-testing-be-carried-out/)

If you have the previous test certificate or can get a copy from the electrician who issued it, there may be an explanation for why a more frequent inspection has been recommended, eg there may have been previous signs of "[green goo](https://www.voltimum.co.uk/articles/green-goo)" in the installation.

Answer (score 2):

The electricity supplier has the right to inspect your home installation whenever. This is in the contract you signed. They just send you a notification...

They can also make a full inspection if you have broken the seals or tags on the supply fuses to get work carried out on the distribution board (aka fuse box) while they are there to re-tag the supply fuses.

So, it can be your favorite electrician or the electricity company or supplier who can test to the standards, which is quite involved and needs some expensive test gear...

They sent a notification to my parents not so long ago... Arrived and tested - all was fine :)